# Passing data from controller to gsp in grails 3.2.8

Tags: grails

I am trying to pass value from controller to gsp. Nothing is displayed in the page.

index.gsp

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>"${greeting}"</h1>
<h1>${greeting}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

controller:

```
def index = {
render(template:'index',model: [greeting:test])
}
```

Thanks
Pooja

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the `index` action in `TestPassValueController` will look like:

```
def index() {
    [greeting: 'test']
}
```

And in `\grails-app\views\testPassValue\index.gsp` you'll have:

```
<h1>${greeting}<\h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!!!I executed the above mentioned in my action and still nothing was displayed

Comment: If you just add text to the body of the gsp do you see this? If not, what is your controller name and what is the name of the directory containing your gsp?

Comment: yes i am able to see the text. The controller name 'TestPassValueController'  and the directory is sample.test.

Comment: The gap directory name should match the controller name minus the word controller so testpassvalue in your case

Comment: I got it displayed by grails clean command. Will it be possible to pass '<h1> testing <h1>' as the data to be retrieved and displayed according in the GSP?